# The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, destroy

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;

    public Vector3 offset;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (target.position != null)
        {
            Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
            Vector3 smoothPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
            transform.position = smoothPosition;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who destoryed target ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access Transform in a particular gameobject, which is your target. But when you destroy it, for example, you can not find it anymore. The console log show that either the gameobject contain the Transform or you can not find Transform in your gameobject

Comment: i remove .position from  if (target.position != null) and it's work

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`target.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) returns a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) which is a [`**struct**`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and **never** can be `null`.

However, if the `target` itself was already destroyed you can't access its position!

What you want to do is rather check

```
if(target)
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothPosition;
}
else
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

which is using the [`UnityEngine.Object` opreator `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

> Does the object exist?

which if you like you could then also do using a [ternary](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) expression

```
transform.position = target ? Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position + offset, smoothSpeed) : Vector2.zero;
```